# Postfix: How to set the minimum number of bits for (non-EC) DH key exchange?

Tags: ssl, postfix

I am currently assessing the TLS security of a Postfix mail server and among other things `sslscan` reported that the server allows a (non-EC) DH exchange with only 1024 bits.

While one solution would be to only allow ECDH(E) and disable DH(E) entirely, I would rather like to keep support for DH(E) for compatibility reasons but only enforce a lower limit on the size of the finite group (maybe 2048 bit, or even 3072 bits preferably).

How do I do that with Postfix? I cannot find any `smptd_tls_...` setting which seems related to that problem.

Comment: Have you configured `smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file`? See https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file

Comment: No, I haven't. According to the docs that shouldn't be necessary as of Postfix 3.8 and is not recommended anymore. I will give it a try though.

Comment: The documentation clearly states the reason for not configuring this in Postfix. Your SSL library should know better. If it does not.. what version of the OpenSSL library are you using, exactly?

Comment: The documentation also tells what to do if you wish to use custom parameters and what are the consequences of each choice. There isn't much to answer besides citing the entire documentation for `smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file`.